# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument

Tags: r, random, sample

I am running the following lines of code and facing the above-mentioned   error. Any ideas how to fix this ?

```r
X <- NULL
S <- NULL
remove.value <- NULL
N <- seq.int(1, 25)
     
repeat {
  S <- sample(N, 1, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
  S
  if (S == 1) {
    remove.value <- c(S, S + 1)
  } else if (S == 25) {
    remove.value <- c(S, S - 1)
  } else {
    remove.value <- c(S - 1, S, S + 1)
  }
  remove.value
  N <- N [which(!(N %in% remove.value))]
  N
  if (is.null(N)) break
}
```

Comment: what does `length(x)` on its own give you?

Comment: What is you overall goal?

Comment: length(N) is most of the runs 22, which sounds right, and occasionally 23.

Comment: goals: I have a vector of int from 0 to 25 (N), I want to select one member of the vector and eliminate its adjacent values and then repeat this as long as I can not do it.

Comment: You don't seem to be storing the sequence of removed values, so I'm guessing this isn't important to you, but if you change `if (is.null(N)) break` to `if(length(N)<1) break` you won't get an error.

Answer (score 5):

It actually works as you intend. You can see it if you insert `print(N)`

```
> repeat{

    S<-sample(N ,1, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
    S
    if (S==1) {
        remove.value<-c(S,S+1)
    } else if (S==25) {
        remove.value<-c(S,S-1)
    }else {remove.value<-c(S-1,S,S+1)
    }
    remove.value

    N <- N [which(N %!in% remove.value)]          
    print(N)

    if (is.null(N)) break
}
 [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 25
 [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 25
 [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 13 14 15 16 17 18 25
 [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 16 17 18 25
[1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 25
[1]  1  2  8  9 25
[1]  8  9 25
[1] 8 9
integer(0)
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

The error is caused by the final value of `N`, which is `integer(0)`, and not `NULL`. If you use `if (length(N)== 0) break` instead of `if (is.null(N)) break` the code works without error message.

Comment: I am seeing an inconsistent behaviour from R studio. I am still seeing the error despite trying to use RStudent's suggestion:                                                
X <- 0
S <- NULL
remove.valuex <- NULL
N <- seq.int(1,25)

 repeat{
  
  S<-sample(N ,1, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
  print(S)
  if (S==1) {
    remove.value<-c(S,S+1)
  } else if (S==25) {
    remove.value<-c(S,S-1)
  }else {remove.value<-c(S-1,S,S+1)
  }
  remove.value
  
  N <- N[which(!N %in% remove.value)]      
  print(N)
  X <- X+1
  print(X)
  if (length(N)== 1) break
}

Comment: I'm using RStudio too, and it works for me. Do you get the same error?

Comment: Yep the same error but every now and then depending on the random sample I guess.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. The biggest source of confusion for me is that the error message mentions `sample.int`, and I'm using `sample`. So it looks like either it's just a sloppy error message, or RStudio is trying to use the wrong function.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the library `Tidyverse` solved this issue for me. The problem seems to be RStudio calling the `sample.int()` instead of simply `sample()`. Cheers!

Comment: same problem and that didn't help for me. Also, sample.int() is baseR

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling with this in an entirely different setting. I think the answer of @DatamineR is correct. You can see this by trying:

```
sample(NULL, 1)
sample(integer(0), 1)
```

where you get the same error message:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

I still find this very misleading because neither of us called sample.int() ;) Doesn't make debugging easier. But for me at least that was the issue, we actually tried to sample from nothing.